# php 7 ctype functions not working in cli mode

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.2

I have a strange problem with php7.2 and 7.1
When I this script in php cli

```
$test = 'helo*oo54 ';
echo $test;
$test = trim($test);
echo $test;
$test = ctype_alnum($test);
echo $test;
```

I get this error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ctype_alnum()

When I run it through the-fpm in the browser it works fine.

Cytpe is enabled in php/7.2/cli/php.ini ( it is by default)
Running on Ubuntu 16.04, php packages installed from ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
```

Comment: on the command line run `php -i` check for "ctype functions => enabled
"

Comment: Thanks, yes that's enabled.

Comment: then what you describe seems impossible ;(

Comment: I know right! The weird thing is when I built a server using the same steps last week I did not have this issue. Almost leads me to believe there could be a bug in compiling the php packages. But I'm sure that is highly unlikely. I can't find anyone else who has reported this problem. So I hope I am not overlooking something stupid.